# I'm looking to pass 1 line of a .txt at a time into a shell script as a grep search argument

Tags: linux, shell, grep

basically trying to make a shell script to run a grep on a certain directory for each line of a particular .txt, then output the results to a .txt that is named the same as the argument.

```
for %EACH_LINE_OF_TEXT% in example.txt{
     grep -ri %CONTENTS_OF_LINE% /searchfolder/ > %CONTENTS_OFLINE%.txt
}
```

very new to linux so i know the syntax of that is horribly wrong but thats the best way of illustrating what im trying to do.

for context this is what my manual searches look like

```
grep -ri search . > search.txt
```

when im in the directory of the stuff im searching ofc

thanks for help

Comment: Avoid the "XY Problem" scenario. Rather than writing "_I'm looking to pass 1 line of a .txt at a time into a shell script as a grep search argument_", say what you want to achieve. In this case it looks like, "_I have a directory of files and I want to match any line of any file against a list (a file) of regular expressions_".

Comment: What's in your `example.txt` file? If there are regular expressions or strings that may be invalid as filenames (e.g. strings containing `/`), then special care must be taken when writing an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while read line ; do
    grep -ri -e "$line" /searchfolder/ > "$line.txt"
done < example.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your answer looks good to me, but would be even more helpful if you would add some additional explanation of what it does exactly and how it works. This helps the original poster to better understand your solution and helps adapting it to other situations in the future. See als [this post with tips on writing a good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Good luck!

Comment: You're right @roaima, updated code.

Comment: It should perhaps be `read -r line` to prevent interpretation of backslash escapes, especially if the file may contain regex patterns (such as `foo\|bar` for example) or even `IFS= read -r line` to allow for patterns with leading whitespace

Comment: I concur with steeldriver: `IFS= read -r line` is the only way to read a line verbatim from the file.

Comment: This would fail if a line contained one or several `/` characters. Depending on what the file contains (search strings or regular expressions), this may not do what the user wants (note: we don't know what the user keeps in the file).